# Диалоговое окно MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

У меня есть диалоговое окно, в котором я, по нажатии кнопки "добавить", заполняю чистенькую форму, а после нажатия "Сохранить" - заношу данные в БД Access.

Дело в том, что не входя в режим добавления записи в БД я могу просто просматривать их, переключая одну запись за другой.Тем самым данные каждой записи записываются в соответствующее поле формы и я их могу просмотреть. Но, когда я нажимаю кнопку добавить, а потом вдруг передумываю добавлять, то отменить добавление, то есть вернуться в режим просмотра записей, я не могу. Вопрос: Как мне реализовать отмену?

Функция добавления:

```
void CShabanStas4View::OnBnClickedRecordAdd2()
{
    CString msg;
    int temp = 0;

    temp = m_pSet->GetRecordCount();
    if (m_pSet->m_ID == 0 || temp == 0)
    {
        ID_counter = temp;
        m_pSet->AddNew();
        CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit *)(this->GetDlgItem(IDC_USER_ID));
        m_pSet->m_ID = ++ID_counter;
        msg.Format(_T("%d"), ID_counter);
        m_bAdding = TRUE;
        CEdit* pCtrl = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_USER_ID);
        int result = pCtrl->SetReadOnly(TRUE);
        UpdateData(FALSE);
        pEdit->SetWindowText(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        OnSortID();
        m_pSet->MoveLast();
        ID_counter = m_pSet->m_ID;
        m_pSet->AddNew();
        CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit *)(this->GetDlgItem(IDC_USER_ID));
        m_pSet->m_ID = ++ID_counter;
        msg.Format(_T("%d"), ID_counter);
        m_bAdding = TRUE;
        CEdit* pCtrl = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_USER_ID);
        int result = pCtrl->SetReadOnly(TRUE);
        UpdateData(FALSE);
        pEdit->SetWindowText(msg);
    }
}
```

А это функция сохранения:

```
void CShabanStas4View::OnBnClickedRecordSave()
{
    m_bAdding = FALSE;
    if (m_pSet->CanUpdate())
    {
        UpdateData(TRUE);

        m_pSet->m_SName = userName;
        m_pSet->m_SLastName = userLastname;
        m_pSet->m_SSurname = userSurname;
        m_pSet->m_SGroupNum = userGroupNum;
        m_pSet->m_SFacultee = userFacultee;
        m_pSet->m_SStudyYear = userCourseNum;
        m_pSet->m_SCourseProjectName = userCourseProjectName;
        m_pSet->m_SDeadLine = userDeadLine;
        m_pSet->Update();
    }
    m_pSet->Requery();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    CEdit* pCtrl = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_USER_ID);
    pCtrl->SetReadOnly(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код добавления.

Comment: ----------Добавил!

Comment: А теперь жди ответа, я на Java пишу! :D

Comment: Понял, я тоже Java неплохо знаю

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на мой вопрос был довольно прост в реализации и краток.
Обработчик кнопки "Отмена":

```
CShabanStas4View::OnBnClickedBack()
{
    m_pSet->Requery();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```